# Replace part of URL by user input for a lot of URL's

Tags: javascript

I have this Array with a lot of URLs:

```
let url_list = ["https://webew00236.be04.eu/request/pdfservice/L2020-29-001DAGS.pdf",
                "https://webew00236.be04.eu/request/pdfservice/L2020-29-001DAGR.pdf",
                "https://webew00236.be04.eu/request/pdfservice/L2020-29-001DEPV.pdf",
                "https://webew00236.be04.eu/request/pdfservice/L2020-29-001DAGF.pdf",
                "https://webew00236.be04.eu/request/pdfservice/L2020-29-001DAGL.pdf",
                "https://webew00236.be04.eu/request/pdfservice/L2020-29-001DAGT.pdf" ,
                "https://webew00236.be04.eu/request/pdfservice/L2020-29-001DAGE.pdf",   
                "https://webew00236.be04.eu/request/pdfservice/L2020-29-001DAGP.pdf",
                "https://webew00236.be04.eu/request/pdfservice/L2020-29-001DEP%25.pdf", 
                "https://webew00236.be04.eu/request/pdfservice/L2020-29-001DAGV.pdf",  
                "https://webew00236.be04.eu/request/pdfservice/L2020-29-001DEPN.pdf",    
                "https://webew00236.be04.eu/request/pdfservice/L2020-29-001DEPL.pdf",  
               ]
```

what I want to achieve is that I loop thru each Url and replace the '29' with something the user inputs.
for example `https://webew00236.be04.eu/request/pdfservice/L2020-29-001DEPL.pdf` changes into `https://webew00236.be04.eu/request/pdfservice/L2020-30-001DEPL.pdf` and that for all urls in the array.

I have tried this
but that's a lot of work If have to do it for every url:

```
function changeText2(){
    var userInput = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
    var lnk = document.getElementById('lnk');
    lnk.href = "https://webew00236.be04.eu/request/pdfservice/L2020-"+ userInput+"-001DAGS.pdf";
    lnk.innerHTML = lnk.href;
}
```

I tried a lot of different things but none of them give me the desired result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `map` and `replace`.

```
const res = url_list.map(url=>url.replace(/(L2020-)29/, "$1" + userInput));
```

```js
let url_list = ["https://webew00236.be04.eu/request/pdfservice/L2020-29-001DAGS.pdf",
                "https://webew00236.be04.eu/request/pdfservice/L2020-29-001DAGR.pdf",
                "https://webew00236.be04.eu/request/pdfservice/L2020-29-001DEPV.pdf",
                "https://webew00236.be04.eu/request/pdfservice/L2020-29-001DAGF.pdf",
                "https://webew00236.be04.eu/request/pdfservice/L2020-29-001DAGL.pdf",
                "https://webew00236.be04.eu/request/pdfservice/L2020-29-001DAGT.pdf" ,
                "https://webew00236.be04.eu/request/pdfservice/L2020-29-001DAGE.pdf",   
                "https://webew00236.be04.eu/request/pdfservice/L2020-29-001DAGP.pdf",
                "https://webew00236.be04.eu/request/pdfservice/L2020-29-001DEP%25.pdf", 
                "https://webew00236.be04.eu/request/pdfservice/L2020-29-001DAGV.pdf",  
                "https://webew00236.be04.eu/request/pdfservice/L2020-29-001DEPN.pdf",    
                "https://webew00236.be04.eu/request/pdfservice/L2020-29-001DEPL.pdf",  
               ];
var userInput = 30;
const res = url_list.map(url=>url.replace(/(L2020-)29/, "$1" + userInput));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: @Quint Glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

The following code will replace `29` with the user input. You only have to append the results to the link :)

```js
let url_list = ["https://webew00236.be04.eu/request/pdfservice/L2020-29-001DAGS.pdf",
  "https://webew00236.be04.eu/request/pdfservice/L2020-29-001DAGR.pdf",
  "https://webew00236.be04.eu/request/pdfservice/L2020-29-001DEPV.pdf",
  "https://webew00236.be04.eu/request/pdfservice/L2020-29-001DAGF.pdf",
  "https://webew00236.be04.eu/request/pdfservice/L2020-29-001DAGL.pdf",
  "https://webew00236.be04.eu/request/pdfservice/L2020-29-001DAGT.pdf",
  "https://webew00236.be04.eu/request/pdfservice/L2020-29-001DAGE.pdf",
  "https://webew00236.be04.eu/request/pdfservice/L2020-29-001DAGP.pdf",
  "https://webew00236.be04.eu/request/pdfservice/L2020-29-001DEP%25.pdf",
  "https://webew00236.be04.eu/request/pdfservice/L2020-29-001DAGV.pdf",
  "https://webew00236.be04.eu/request/pdfservice/L2020-29-001DEPN.pdf",
  "https://webew00236.be04.eu/request/pdfservice/L2020-29-001DEPL.pdf",
];

const replaceByUserInput = (user_input) => {
  return url_list.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    return [...acc, curr.replace(/-29-/g, `-${user_input}-`)];
  }, []);
}



document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const userInput = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
  const replacedResult = replaceByUserInput(userInput);
  console.log(replacedResult);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="userInput" />
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I'm going with the above solution, a lot shorter :)

Comment: Cool :) My code sample is a bit more elaborate since it includes some UI operations.